# Android Studio highlights Java code for no apparent reason.

Tags: android-studio

NOTE: Please let me know if this not the appropriate place for this question and I will move it.

I am using the RecognEyes font theme, and I noticed this annoying light army green highlight:

[image: Weird highlight of anonymous function]

I noticed that it highlights exactly my anonymous class declaration, but in the font settings on Android Studio, I don't see this color scheme being applied:
[image]

Please let me know if there is some Java syntax here that I'm not aware of which is causing this specific section to be highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

I've answered my own question - the highlight means there is a linting issue.